# JFrame - Start on top, but not always

Tags: java, swing, jframe, always-on-top

I want to show a `JFrame` on top of my Main `JFrame` on start of the program. But not "always on top"!

Setting the frame visible at the end of the Main-Method in my Main frame doesn’t do the trick...

So how can I make a frame showing on top on startup, but then hide when I click on another frame?

Comment: Looks like you need a splash screen. See http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077467/core-java/java-tip-104--make-a-splash-with-swing.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRzD937tkEU

Comment: I dint know if this is the right "thing" for me... I already have a JFrame with tables, code etc... i just want to show it on top on start up

Comment: You can use a modal dialog, this will prevent the main window from been bright in front of the dialog window. Y can also use the bringToFront method to bring a window to the top of the visible stack

Comment: Where should i use the bringToFront method? Tried it in my MainFrame, and in the Frame which should be on top, doesnt work